# How to make tcl interpreter not to continue after exit command?

Tags: c++, tcl, exit

```
static int
MyReplacementExit(ClientData unused, Tcl_Interp *interp, int argc, const char *argv[])
{
 //     Tcl_DeleteInterp(interp);
 //     Tcl_Finalize();
        return TCL_OK;
}

int main() {
    Tcl_Interp *interp = Tcl_CreateInterp(); 
    Tcl_CreateCommand(interp, "exit", MyReplacementExit, NULL, NULL);

    Tcl_Eval(interp, "exit ; puts 11111111");
    std::cout << "22222222222" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I need to handle `exit` command evaluation of tcl interpreter. By default it tries to delete itself and also calls `std::exit` which closes whole program.It is not what I want so I am trying to replace it by custom proc. I dont need to delete interpreter in exit handler proc(I can do it later), only need it to not continue evaluating commands after `exit` command.

In this code I need to change `MyReplacementExit` proc somehow, so `11111111` doesn't be printed but 
`22222222222` does printed.

It can be achieved by returning `TCL_ERROR` from `MyReplacementExit` proc, but then I can't distinguish other error situations from this.

Comment: Did you try to call [`Tcl_CancelEval`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclLib/Cancel.htm) from your `exit` replacement?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn This may be a solution but my tcl version is 8.4 and it doesn't support Tcl_CancelEval

Comment: What about returning TCL_BREAK or TCL_CONTINUE in MyReplacementExit? Will it skip the execution of commands following your redefined 'exit'?

Comment: $VictorBurenkov that will not work when exit is called from proc. needed to work as original exit command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your replacement for `exit` delete the interpreter (which stops further commands from being executed, but doesn't actually immediately delete the data structure as it is still in use) and, *important*, wrap the call to `Tcl_Eval` with calls to `Tcl_Preserve` and `Tcl_Release`. Don't call `Tcl_Finalize` if you can possibly avoid it; that is for when you're about to unload the Tcl library from memory and can be quite tricky (it's easier to just quit the process, frankly).

Here's how to do it with your code (adapted):

```
static int
MyReplacementExit(ClientData unused, Tcl_Interp *interp, int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    Tcl_DeleteInterp(interp);  // <------------------
    return TCL_OK;
}

int main() {
    Tcl_Interp *interp = Tcl_CreateInterp(); 
    Tcl_CreateCommand(interp, "exit", MyReplacementExit, NULL, NULL);

    Tcl_Preserve(interp);      // <------------------
    Tcl_Eval(interp, "exit ; puts 11111111");
    Tcl_Release(interp);       // <------------------
    std::cout << "22222222222" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Be aware that you should *not* access the interpreter *at all* after the `Tcl_Release` as it might've been destroyed (as in, the memory released and scribbled over with random junk) at that point. If you need to retrieve results and use them (e.g., printing them out) do so beforehand.

Note that in this specific case, you don't need the preserve/release pair; your code isn't actually touching the interpreter after the `Tcl_Eval` (which does its own preserve/release internally).

---

If you don't want the interpreter to terminate, that's much trickier. The cleanest way in 8.4 is probably to throw a custom exception code (i.e., anything greater than `TCL_CONTINUE`) but there's no guarantee that it will work for arbitrary code as Tcl's `catch` command can still trap it. If you're really in that situation, it's actually easier to create an interpreter, run the arbitrary code in the sub-interp, and tear it down at the end of the script; you can then drop that interpreter without losing much context. Indeed, you could do:

```
Tcl_Preserve(interp);
if (Tcl_Eval(interp, theScriptToEval) != TCL_OK)
    // Handle unexpected errors here
if (!Tcl_InterpDeleted(interp))
    Tcl_DeleteInterp(interp);
Tcl_Release(interp);
```

Yes, this will mean you want to keep the amount of work you do to set up the interpreter fairly small; you probably won't want to try to call this every millisecond on an interrupt…